# Messages answers Grouped By the Parent Original Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to group messages by the Messages Answers like this:

- Message id = 1
- Message answer id = 2 / Parent Message id = 1
- Message answer id = 3 / Parent Message id = 1
- Message answer id = 4 / Parent Message id = 1
- Message id = 5
- Message answer id = 6 / Parent Message id = 5
- Message answer id = 7 / Parent Message id = 5
- Message answer id = 8 / Parent Message id = 5

The Message model:

```
public class Message
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string NameFrom { get; set; }
    public string EmailFrom { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneFrom { get; set; }

    public string NameTo { get; set; }
    public string EmailTo { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneTo { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
    public bool? Approved { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateRead { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public Member MemberFrom { get; set; }
    public Member MemberTo { get; set; }
    public MessageType MessageType { get; set; }
    public Message MessageParent { get; set; }

    public Ad Ad { get; set; }
    public Ask Ask { get; set; }
}
```

To presente it in the View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="message_link_container" id="linkmessage_@item.Id">
        <ul class="estr_message" id="estrmessage_@item.Id">
            <li id="email_@item.Id">
                <p>@if(item.MessageParent_Id == 0){ if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.NameFrom)) { @item.EmailFrom } else { @item.NameFrom } }</p>
            </li>
            <li id="title_@item.Id">
                <p>@item.Title</p>
            </li>
            <li id="date_@item.Id">
                <p>@item.DateCreated</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: You have an odd Message model.  You have removed the navigation property to the children based on parent id, otherwise this would be fairly trivial. Additionally, you ask for it to be grouped by "Messages Answers", but your model doesn't have any mention of "Answers".

Comment: Hi, thanks. The message answer is a Message with a MessageParent != NULL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var model=Messages
             .OrderBy(o=>o.MessageParent_Id==0?Id:o.MessageParent_Id)
             .ThenBy(o=>o.Id);
```

Comment: Although, I wouldn't use just an ordered list of Messages myself.  I would actually create the navigation to children, and return the messages that have no parent, and have its children collection populated with the children.  Then change the view to match.  Unless you are expecting a very deep relationship with a high number of generations.  Then that might require a bit more thought.